# Heroku pgbackups restore resource not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, migrate

I am currently trying to migrate a database  on one app to another in heroku by following this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrate-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups

After running:

```
 heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_TURQUOISE -a target-app \
`heroku pgbackups:url -a source-app`
```

I end up with a "Resource not found error"

I'm sure I will need to post more information/logs but I'm not quite sure what is needed.

Comment: Also, when I try to restore the snapshot on the heroku dashboard I get a "Transfer unavailable" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug, try just doing `heroku pgbackups:url -a source-app` and entering that URL in your browser. This command should download and install into your local Postgres database `db`:

```
curl `heroku pgbackups:url -a source-app` | pg_restore --verbose --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d db -n public"
```

Answer (score 1):

Farther down in this [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups#transfering-databases-between-heroku-applications) it references migrating between apps, which seems like what you are trying to do.

The example syntax given is: `$ heroku pgbackups:transfer HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE -a sushi`